# how to use cbind command to get values of variables for each value of rho

Tags: r

I m working with r and  i want to use cbind command to get results  for each value of rho.but get one value for each value of rho instead of n=3

```
muy=100; mux=50; sigy=10; sigx=7
n=3; sim=5    
rho=seq(-1,1,0.5)
ybark <- numeric(sim)
for(j in 1:length(rho)) {
  for(i2 in 1:sim) {
    z1 = rnorm(n)
    z2= rnorm(n)
    x = sqrt(1-rho[j]^2)*sigx*z1[j] + rho[j]*sigx*z2[j] + mux
    y = sigy*z2[j] + muy
    ybark[i2] = (mean(y)*mean(x))/mux
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your desired output? Try to fix be yourself the code which is presenting a lot of mistakes: you can't use ";" like this, z1 has 3 elements and j could be equal to 5 so z1[j] gives an error, ....

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve]! At the current state your question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: You can use Excel or anything you're comfortable with to at least show a desired output (even a screenshot of it would work). If you cannot communicate the problem statement clearly and plainly enough, you're not going to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
muy=100 ;mux=50 ; sigy=10; sigx=7
n=3;sim=5;rho=seq(-1,1,0.5)
ybark<-list()
for(j in 1:length(rho)){
    for(i2 in 1:sim)
    {
        z1 = rnorm(n)
        z2= rnorm(n)
        x = sqrt(1-rho[j]^2)*sigx*z1[j] + rho[j]*sigx*z2[j] + mux
        y = sigy*z2[j] + muy
        ybark[[paste(j,i2,sep="_")]] = (mean(y)*mean(x))/mux
    }
}
n<-length(ybark)/length(rho);grp<-rep(1:n,each=sim)
tapply(ybark,grp,function(x)matrix(x,nrow=1))
```

is that what you want?

```
$`1`
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]   
[1,] 99.88803 92.99583 101.0367 98.73194 99.4599

$`2`
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
[1,] 111.9889 87.19593 111.1355 86.76358 91.04678

$`3`
     [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]   
[1,] 135.2721 93.4944 71.71243 121.4449 84.8635

$`4`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  

$`5`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```